# Exporting from QGIS to .dxf as blocks?

Tags: qgis, export, dxf, block

I'm exporting from QGIS 3.4 to ACAD .dxf format.
Since I made this in QGIS 2.18 all features exported were blocks in Autocad, but now I find out that every single geometry is exported exploded in the .dxf format.

How do I export them as blocks?